# Align items inside a collapse bottom bar on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a bottom bar that will be collapsed when scrolling.
I cannot vertically align its content in the center no matter what I do.

```css
.Bar {
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
}

.barElement {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 22%;
  float: left;
}

.barEContainer {
  background-color: green; /* this one will not be vertically centered! */
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Bar" id="Bar">
  <div class="barElement">
    <div class="barEContainer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `barEContainer` will never be vertically aligned. I would like to put it (the green background here) exactly in the middle.

On different mobile screens it will appear vertically on different positions (not middle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `barElement` a flexbox with `align-items: center` for vertical centering. Also add `width: 100%` to the `barEContainer` and remove its `margin-top` - see demo below:

```css
.Bar {
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
}

.barElement {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 22%;
  float: left;
  display: flex; /* added */
  align-items: center; /* added */
}

.barEContainer {
  background-color: green; /* this one will not be vertically centered! */
  height: 50%;
  /* margin-top: 25%;*/
  width: 100%; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="Bar" id="Bar">
  <div class="barElement">
    <div class="barEContainer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```